Gstreamer uses appsink to get frames and then uses opencv to display the picture, which will be blocked
I use Gstreamer's appsink to get each frame of the video stream. Now I want to display it through opencv's imshow window. The terminal is blocked after printing a frame of message. What is the problem?
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/app/gstappsink.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#define CAPS "video/x-raw,format=RGB,pixel-aspect-ratio=1/1"

typedef struct _CustomData {
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source;
    GstElement *jitterbuffer;
    GstElement *depayloader;
    GstElement *avdec;
    GstElement *convert;
    GstElement *sink;
    GMainLoop *main_loop;
    std::string rtsp_path;
} CustomData;

std::mutex display_mutex;

static GstFlowReturn new_sample(GstElement *sink, CustomData *data) {
    GstSample *sample;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstCaps *caps;
    GstMapInfo map;
    gint width, height;

    g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample);
    if (sample) {
        buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
        caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
        GstStructure *s = gst_caps_get_structure(caps, 0);
        gst_structure_get_int(s, "width", &width);
        gst_structure_get_int(s, "height", &height);

        if (gst_buffer_map(buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ)) {
            cv::Mat frame(height, width, CV_8UC3, (void*)map.data);

            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(display_mutex);
            cv::Mat grayImage;
            cv::Mat binaryImage;
        
            if (!frame.empty()) {       
                cv::imshow(data->rtsp_path, frame);
                cv::waitKey(1); 
            }
            

            gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);
        }
        gst_sample_unref(sample);
    }
    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

static void pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {
    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->jitterbuffer, "sink");
    if (gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad)) {
        gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
        return;
    }

    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    const gchar *new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

    if (!g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "application/x-rtp")) {
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
        gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
        return;
    }

    gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
    gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
}

void start_pipeline(CustomData *data) {
    gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);

    data->pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");
    data->source = gst_element_factory_make("rtspsrc", "source");
    data->jitterbuffer = gst_element_factory_make("rtpjitterbuffer", "jitterbuffer");
    data->depayloader = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "depayloader");
    data->avdec = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "avdec");
    data->convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "convert");
    data->sink = gst_element_factory_make("appsink", "sink");

    g_object_set(data->source, "location", data->rtsp_path.c_str(), NULL);
    g_object_set(data->sink, "emit-signals", TRUE, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(data->sink, "new-sample", G_CALLBACK(new_sample), data);
    g_signal_connect(data->source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), data);

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(data->pipeline), data->source, data->jitterbuffer, data->depayloader, data->avdec, data->convert, data->sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many(data->jitterbuffer, data->depayloader, data->avdec, data->convert, data->sink, NULL);

    data->main_loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    g_main_loop_run(data->main_loop);

    gst_element_set_state(data->pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(data->pipeline));
    g_main_loop_unref(data->main_loop);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    XInitThreads();
    std::vector<std::string> rtsp_paths = {
        //"rtsp://admin:1q2w3e4r@192.168.2.167:557/LiveMedia/ch1/Media1",
        //"rtsp://admin:1q2w3e4r@192.168.2.172:562/h264/ch1/av_stream",
        "rtsp://admin:1q2w3e4r@192.168.2.171:561/h264/ch1/av_stream"
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<CustomData> data(rtsp_paths.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rtsp_paths.size(); ++i) {
        data[i].rtsp_path = rtsp_paths[i];
        threads.emplace_back(start_pipeline, &data[i]);
    }

    for (auto &t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}


I tried to call imshow separately, and used threads to run opencv separately, but it didn't work. I also tried to modify the waitkey time. I hope opencv can display the read frames in the window, which is convenient for testing.

break into the process with a debugger. where does it stop?

[Thread 0xffff877f9900 (LWP 2687210) exited]
GDB debugging shows that it will block after creating a thread
imshow will display a frame of the picture

what happens if you remove the imshow and waitkey and perhaps replace that by a log line? I'd like to confirm that that works correctly. -- whatever GUI library is used by OpenCV on your system (cout << cv::getBuildInformation()) might not appreciate getting called from various different threads or even just the same thread that isn't the main thread.

Yeah, the HighGUI stuff inside a callback that's potentially called from multiple threads is asking for trouble. Not to mention running the waitKey while holding the lock... you basically hold it for several milliseconds while doing very little actual work. This needs a serious re-think. Have a single thread responsible for visualization, and able to skip frames as necessary to keep up with the streams.

If imshow is not used, the program will obtain data normally and can run normally
